# How to Set Product video url Programitically in magento2.2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, script, product-video

I have created a script for import CSV products everything's working perfect but one issue is product video url not set.

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');

// add bootstrap
$bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$object_Manager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();

$app_state = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$set_product = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

try{
     $set_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
     $set_product->setVideoUrl('youtub.com/magento');
     $set_product->save();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: did you get any solution for this

Comment: no not now. waiting..